# Error with function pointer returning a (void *)

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm getting a compilation error that states " 'foo' declared as function returning a function" because of a line in my program:

```
typedef void * (* foo)(void *)(int);
```

where foo is a function pointer to a function that takes a (void *) type and and int and returns a (void *) type. As I understand it, the declaration above is not returning a function, but a pointer. Is the issue with using a typedef in this situation? The only difference between this function pointer and others I've been using is the (void *) argument, so I assume the problem is related to that. I'm using gcc on a linux machine.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration is wrong. The error message makes sense, since `foo`, as you wrote it, is declared to be a type alias for "pointer to function receiving `void *` and returning a function that receives `int` and returns `void *`.

If the function receives a `void *` and an `int`, you should have this instead:

```
typedef void *(*foo)(void *, int);
```

This essentially translates to "Let foo denote the type pointer to function receiving a `void *` and an `int` and returning a `void *`"

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I'm not sure why I thought each argument had to be encapsulated with () instead of separated by a ",".